# Java beginner; errors after copying simple sample code? Is my configuration messed up?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am one week into learning Java. Suddenly, I have a problem with red squigglies on the line where function that tell me that a ; semicolon or parentheses ) is expected. All my searching has led nowhere, maybe it's a missing import or a setting in my configuration that is not correct.

I am copying the code from this tutorial, at least I believe I have copied it correctly. All works fine until trying to put this function in. What am I doing wrong?

[YouTube Tutorial that I am using...please watch](https://youtu.be/eCBAZUlHVT0?t=68)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
            numbers.add(i);
        display(numbers);

        // the next line has errors of ';' expected & ')' expected.
        static void display(ArrayList arr){
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(arr.get(i) + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the class Main have anything to do with it? There are no other files here, wouldn't think that would matter, but that's not working either.

Comment: what is exactly the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bracket at the end of the function

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
            numbers.add(i);
        display(numbers);
    } // this bracket

    public static void display(ArrayList arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(arr.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got it! I see it. Phew. Glad to look like a noob and be able to move on. Thanks, Mick.